# Дамп медиа чата Telegram с помощью Telethon

Tags: python, telethon, telegram, media

Всем привет!
Хочу сделать полный дамп нескольких чатов. Сначала хочу разобраться с медиа.
Но с моим кодом скачивается только последние два года из шести. Выдают такую ошибку:

**The file reference has expired and is no longer valid or it belongs to self-destructing media and cannot be resent (caused by GetFileRequest)**

Не смог найти в гугле что это точно означает и как это исправить.
Вот код:

```
def download_all(channels, client):
    for target in channels:
        try:
            print(f'Starting with {target.title}...')
            for msg in tqdm(client.get_messages(target, None)):
                try:
                    msg.download_media(f".//{target.title}-{date.today()}//")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Smth goes wrong: {e}")
                    continue
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Smth goes wrong: {e} \ntrying another target")
            continue
        else:
            print('\nDone!')
```

Comment: Неужели необходим был этот сарказм? Я не понимаю что это значит и дело не в переводе. Если не хотите помогать - всегда можно промолчать, нежели так

Comment: OK, извините за сарказм, тут просто масса запросов от людей, не желающих даже перевод сделать. Но мне странно, что перевод не понятен. Вот перевод: "он принадлежит к самоуничтожающимся носителям, и не может быть повторно отправлен" - иными словами, то, что вы пытаетесь скачать, с очень большой вероятностью просто защищено от копирования, как минимум, такими средствами.

Comment: Кроме того, первая часть говорит, что просто ссылка могла истечь. В таком случае имеет смысл не начинать скачивание, пока не скачается всё по первой ссылке. Вот - достаточно легко нашлось за 5 минут: <https://github.com/Dineshkarthik/telegram_media_downloader/issues/52> Bот конкретный совет: "We should catch this FILE_REFERENCE_EXPIRED exception and re-fetch the message to get the updated file_reference and use it to download the file."

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать решить задачку